# Convert unicode escaped code to unicode char

Tags: c, json, unicode-escapes

On my program written in C, I receive a string with Unicode escaped chars. I would like to convert them on unescaped char to print them.

```
char *string[32];
memset(string, 0, sizeof(string));
strcpy(buffer, "{\"key\":\"\\u25BA\"}");
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

Display: {"key":"\u25BA"}

How convert the Unicode char to display it?

Comment: What does the variable `buffer` come from? And why do you need an array of 32 *pointers* to characters?

Comment: And instead of `\\u25BA` perhaps you should have `\u25BA`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I mean, that’s the whole point of this question, isn’t it? OP is probably receiving the (JSON…) data with the escape-encoded string and wants do decode these escape sequences.

Comment: Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to create a proper [mre] and how to [edit] your questions.

Comment: The data is clearly JSON, so you should use a JSON library to parse it.  Any decent parser will handle the unescaping for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a JSON parser to parse the document, and use a JSON serializer to serialize it. (The JSON library you use should provide both.) Of course, you would need a serializer that doesn't use `\u` sequences when serializing.

A variation of this is to pipe the output to an external tool that does exactly this (e.g. `jq .`).

Alternatively, due to the limits of JSON, it would be safe to search the string for instances of `\u` that aren't preceded by an odd number of `\`. Then it's a question of converting the following hex sequence into the number it represents. If the resulting character is `\` or `"`, or if it's value is less than 0x20, you'll need to handle it specially. Otherwise, encode the result using UTF-8.